# VBA / Excel : Possibility to copy formula dynamically

Tags: vba, excel, formula, copy-paste

I want to copy a formular from one Cell to another in the same row with VBA,

e.g.

```
E1 = "=(E441+E747+E750)*-1"
to
  F1 -> = "=(F441+F747+F750)*-1"
```

But this code snippet:

```
Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim lRow As Long


lRow = tbXlApp.WorksheetFunction.Match("Test", Range("C:C"), 0)

'Line 4
tbXlWs.Cells(lRow, 5).Formula = "=(E441+E747+E750)*-1"

For Each r In tbXlWs.Range(tbXlWs.Cells(lRow, 6), tbXlWs.Cells(lRow, 4 + x))
    r.Formula = tbXlWs.Cells(lRow, 5).Formula
Next r
```

Simply pastes the formula of the cell defined in Line 4.

Recalling the example, it results in

```
   E1 = "=(E441+E747+E750)*-1"
   to
     F1 -> = "=(E441+E747+E750)*-1
```

But it should be Column F in this scenario. What do I need to change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the formulas at one time:

```
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = tbXlApp.WorksheetFunction.Match("Test", Range("C:C"), 0)

'Line 4
tbXlWs.Range(tbXlWs.Cells(lRow, 5), tbXlWs.Cells(lRow, 4 + x)).Formula = "=(E441+E747+E750)*-1"
```

Each formula is then adjusted based on the relative columns, just as if you copied it within Excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Line 4
tbXlWs.Cells(lRow, 5).Formula = "=(E441+E747+E750)*-1"
```

Change this to

```
tbXlWs.Cells(lRow, 5).Formula = "=(F441+F747+F750)*-1"
```

Comment: Hi Maddy, sorry I was not clear enough at this point. I meant that I need to copy the first formula and paste it to several cells, so that the formula adjusts dynamically (as it would be if you go into an excel, copy a cell containing a formula, and paste it somewhere else. Then, the formula changed :-)